# Comment traduire « software framework » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, informatique

Comment traduire « *software framework* » en français dans un document officiel comme un CV par exemple ?

Est ce qu'on peut l'utiliser comme ça ?

J'ai aussi trouvé deux alternatives mais je ne sais pas si elles sont correctes :

> structure logicielle

et

> cadre logiciel

Comment: Je dirais *"environnement de développement"* et je n'utiliserais pas le mot cadre, car tous les frameworks ne sont pas des cadres rigides. Car framework est finalement un terme extrêmement générique. À ne pas confondre avec *Environnement de Développement Intégré* (de l'anglais IDE) qui est le logiciel. Donc *environnement de développement* me semble assez juste pour les deux termes, même s'il peut aussi faire penser à l'OS ou logiciels utilisés... ce qui ne colle pas. Bref, bonne question, j'attends les réponses.

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling Je pense que l'utilisation de "environnement de développement" est très risquée, car serait très facilement confondue avec l'IDE. Personnellement, à la lecture du terme "environnement de développement", je me suis immédiatement dit "mais ça n'a rien à voir avec un IDE, pourquoi il dit ça ?".

Comment: Wikipedia a une réponse cohérente pour ce mot framework: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework#Traduction_française

Answer (score 14):

J'aurais tendance à dire que dans le milieu informatique, le terme *framework* est plutôt globalement reconnu et accepté, même en français, donc dans le cadre d'un CV, je n'hésiterais pas à traduire *Software framework* par *framework logiciel*.

Rien de très officiel, mais il y a un article wikipedia en français sur les [framework](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework).

À mon avis, *structure* et *cadre* sont trop "faibles" pour représenter ce qu'est effectivement un framework.

Answer (score 8):

Le terme "cadriciel" existe, mais n'est que très peu utilisé...Dans un CV "framework" est acceptable (même si on peut lui reprocher un véritable flou : ni bibliothèque, ni logiciel, ni modèle...Qu'est-ce que cet object informatique ? Je suis moi même informaticien et j'utilise pourtant ce mot trop souvent !)

Answer (score 4):

La meilleur traduction pour **«framework»** serait **«structure logicielle»**.

Cependant, dans le monde courant de l'informatique, on peut dire framework et c'est accepté. Je pense que **structure logicielle** est moins bien compris que **framework**.

Comment: Je confirme que si je parle de _structure logicielle_, peu de mes collègues risquent de comprendre à quoi je fais allusion. Et je travaille pourtant en ce moment au sein de l'« équipe Framework » de mon client (oui, elle s'appelle comme ça et elle est responsable du framework d'entreprise).

Comment: j'aime beaucoup l'idée de "structure logicielle". Même si ce n'est clairement pas utilisé dans le langage courant... Mais le problème de l'utilisation vient du fait que "framework" est très très très répandu... donc ce serait une alternative intéressante, qui est très claire, mais qui doit faire son apparition...

Comment: La "structure logicielle" fait plutôt référence à une une architecture choisie par l'équipe d'analyse, alors que le "framework" fait plutôt référence à une architecture imposée, conventionnée. Si on me demande quelle "structure logicielle" j'ai choisie, j'aurais plus tendance à répondre en terme de patrons de conception qu'avec un nom de framework

Comment: @Thiht Au sein de certaines entreprises, il existe des équipes _Framework_ (je travaille au sein de l'une d'elles) qui définissent l'architecture à respecter. On parle donc dans ce cas de framework pour des conventions défini par l'entreprise pour l'entreprise. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 Par ailleurs, une équipe d'analyse ne va pas définir selon moi une _structure logicielle_ au sens « framework », qui a la vocation de s'appliquer à plusieurs projets, mais une _architecture logicielle_ (le mot figure d'ailleurs dans votre commentaire), cette architecture devant se plier aux normes de la structure définie par des échelons supérieurs ayant une vision plus globale de l'organisation informatique dans laquelle s'inscrit le projet.

Comment: @Chop : D'accord, je ne connaissais pas la dénomination "équipe Framework" et je ne pensais pas qu'il y avait une vraie distinction entre "structure logicielle" et "architecture logicielle".

Answer (score 4):

Dans un cadre professionnel, la meilleure traduction du "framework" serait ... "framework". Après si le but c'est justement d'apporter une explication, "structure logicielle" reprend l'idée de "cadre (frame)" et permet un distingo avec un SDK (kit de développement) qui n'apporte pas cette "structure".

Answer (score 4):

@Cl-r a proposé le mot suivant :

> Cadre logiciel

Je proposerai pour ma part, le mot suivant :

> Cadriciel

Il me semble que le mot existe déjà car l'on retrouve quelques occurences de ce mot sur le web. Il y a notamment la [page Wikipedia du mot Cadriciel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cadriciel&redirect=no) qui redirige vers le mot Framework.

Selon moi, le mot *cadriciel* a plusieurs avantages :

- Le mot est court, et aussi facile à prononcer que le mot anglais.
- Il est riche sémantiquement car la référence aux mots « cadre » et « logiciel » est présente.
- Il a l'avantage d'être un mot nouveau. Il n'y a donc pas de risques de confusion avec d'autres mots comme « structure logicielle » ou « boite à outils ».

Il n'est que la contraction de l'expression « cadre logiciel », mais cela fait pourtant une grande différence à mes yeux.

Comment: J'aime beaucoup ce mot-valise. La difficulté de trouver un terme qui aurait une chance de s'imposer face à « framework » est que la plupart des propositions sont composées de deux mots ou plus, et est donc moins aisé à prononcer. Passer d'un mot bisyllabique à un trisyllabique paraît beaucoup plus envisageable. Merci.

Comment: Oui, et parfois l'usage fait que l'on accepte les mots plus long, quitte à les raccourcir plus tard.
Computer -> Ordinateur -> Ordi (dans le langage oral)

Answer (score 3):

Le mot Socle est également bien adapté ici : Ensemble de composants qui constituent la base solide et stable d'une construction ou d'un édifice.

Answer (score 1):

Entendu comme proposition lors d'un exposé :

> Nous entendrons ici le mot framework comme *atelier logiciel*, ...

et framework a été utilisé dans la suite de la présentation, car plus facile dire, chacun ayant son point de vue selon son rôle, concepteur (favorable à l'atelier et à ses contraintes) ou utilisateur (favorable au cadre de travail, l'écran qu'il voit).

L'*atelier logiciel* est en effet un *cadre de travail* très structuré, normalisé tant au niveau des procédures, des méthodes, des contrôles...

Il y a aussi l'ancien mot *progiciel* qui est la base du framework, une suite logique et programmée d'actions pour des résultats ciblés ; audible par tout public.

Les modes se démodant par principe, pour "rentrer dans le *cadre*" pourquoi ne pas essayer de proposer :

> Cadre logiciel.

que l'on ne peut confondre avec un cadre logicien.

Comment: J'ai aussi entendu parler de "boite à outils logicielle", qui est dans la même idée, qui est une image intéressante, mais très lourde...

Comment: J'aime beaucoup. Cela ne me satisfait toujours pas complètement, mais j'aime beaucoup.

Comment: @Random Je l'ai citée en question. :) C'est effectivement représentatif d'un des deux aspects (on n'a pas la notion de cadre, structure). C'est le nom que nous avions utilisé pour un mini-framework que j'avais mis au point sur une autre mission (je n'ai plus l'acronyme, mais le T de WITS signifiait _toolkit_). Si on ne précise pas « logiciel » à chaque fois, ce n'est pas _si_ lourd, même si ça reste toujours plus long que le bisyllabique « framework ».

Comment: Je ne trouve pas que *boîte à outils* soit très adapté. En anglais et comme dit plus haut, c'est *toolkit*. Et les développeurs anglophones savent très bien faire la différence entre *framework* et *toolkit*. Un *framework*, c'est beaucoup plus qu'une boîte à outils, car il y a aussi la notion de structure. Dans un sens, je trouve que la qualification de boîte à outils, pour le coup, colle plus à une librairie.

Comment: @cl-r Le mot progiciel définit une réalité autre que _framework_. La traduction anglaise est _software package_ : le [progiciel](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/progiciel) est une application, un logiciel livrable et livré à l'utilisateur, autosuffisant pour couvrir tous les besoins d'un domaine métier. Le framework ne fournit que des éléments et briques de constructions aux développeurs qui vont mettre au point le progiciel. En ce sens, le framework constitue les fondations ; le logiciel, la petite maison ; et le progiciel, le « building tout de verre et d'acier ».

Answer (score 1):

Enfin des traductions officielles comme 
    *cadre* ou
    *atelier*.

Marre de l'utilisation de termes anglais en français qui ne sont pas dans le dictionnaire.

Pour ma part, je pense que l'utilisation du terme 
    *structure* 
est peu recommandé car il peut être confondu avec les structures dans les languages orientés objet.

*cadre web* ou *atelier web* me convient très bien pour la traduction de *web framework.*

Comment: Parce que l'emploi de « web » en français c'est... « français » ? les « traductions officielles comme cadre ou atelier » (si c'est ce que vous cherchez sont publiés  sur [France Terme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=framework&francetermeSearchDomaine=18&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search)

Comment: On va être réaliste, sur un cv, essayer de traduire ce genre de mot est inutile voir nuisible. Personnellement si je reçois le CV de quelqu'un traduisant "framework" par "atelier", je ne comprendrai pas puisqu'il n'est jamais usité. De plus, cela pourrait nuire à la personne, le recruteur pouvant penser qu'il a traduit sans raison et est donc soit mauvais en français, soit non compétent dans le domaine (je le dis après discussion avec des collègues).

Comment: @Laure Effectivement <i>web</i> n'est pas français. 
<i>Web Framework</i> devient alors <i>Environnement de développement pour la toile</i> à mon avis.

Comment: @Gautier C
Je trouve particulièrement énervant le fait que l'on se croit meilleur en informatique parceque l'on utilise des termes anglais alors que l'on s'exprime en français.
C'est comme enregistrer la télé aujourd'hui, les habitudes que l'on avait avec le magnétoscope ne sont pas passées facilement avec les enregistreurs numériques. 
Le fait d'être obligé de développer en anglais et d'avoir des informaticiens à la place des concepteurs d'un site rendent un site français influencé dès la base par la langue anglaise. Le français c'est mieux quand on parle français.

Comment: @Mantisse c'est votre avis. C'est pas le problème de se croire meilleur, c'est une réalité en entreprise. L'informatique est anglophone, parce qu'il est souvent sujet à un contexte international. Rien ne m'agace plus que de la doc en français quand je dois améliorer une application. Dès que je bosse avec un étranger, il faut lui expliquer l'utilisation des fonctions etc... parce que quelqu'un a pensé que l'on devait traduire tout en français. C'est non productif la plupart du temps en informatique, voilà tout. Mais je suis d'accord pour les sites, qui sont en général propre à une entreprise.

Comment: @Gautier C Je prends un exemple de base : combien de petits groupes français chantent en anglais parceque "ça sonne mieux", voire même, parceque les auteurs n'assument pas ce qu'ils écrivent en français. Quel est le public de ces groupes en général : l'entourage, des amis, des badauds, bref des français la plupart du temps. Pour un groupe international comme Shaka Ponk, d'accord, il y a une chanteuse d'origine britannique et un chanteur français qui chantent tous les deux en français ET en anglais, là, c'est bien. Sinon, marre des groupes français qui n'écrivent pas en français.

Comment: @Mantisse je suis d'accord concernant la musique, voir pleins d'autres choses, mais l'informatique est un domaine particulier, où l'utilisation du français (et des autres langues que l'anglais en général) est un frein à la collaboration, sauf en restant dans des PME françaises, mais dès que l'on est dans un groupe porté à l'international c'est anglais obligatoire (de même dans le domaine de la recherche).

Answer (score 1):

"**Socle logiciel**" répond bien à la définition de "framework".
Il n'est pas utilisé pour autre chose, tout en étant compréhensible dans le milieu informatique.
Je l'ai même déjà vu utilisé dans des docs qui font l'effort du français, et j'ai tout de suite compris de quoi il s'agissait: Je l'ai re-traduit en "framework" dans ma tête. Honte à moi!