# Difficultly trying to translate web development words

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, informatique

I can't seem to find the exact matching of IT-related words to translate a CV. 
For example, some of the words and their closest interpretations I found online are:

> front end = frontend
>    back end = arrière
>    frameworks = cadres
>    server side = du côté serveur

These don't make any sense at all. I don't generally rely on Google translate, but there is nothing better to look for in this case.

If anyone want to go further to help, [here is](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=7687991) the actual list I am having problems with.

Comment: About framework, please see [this post](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/8492/7321)

Comment: Yeah, that is a good one. I think I will go with 'Framework' for that.

Comment: To translate technical words, I usually go on Wikipedia: find the english page, and switch to the french one on the bottom left. Of course sometimes the french page doesn't exist.

Comment: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11897/comment-traduire-front-end-et-back-end + http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do;jsessionid=?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000029461191&dateTexte=&oldAction=dernierJO&categorieLien=id

Comment: As a side remark, CCS should be CSS

Comment: Ah, of course. It was Google translate that changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Front end / Back end

In France, we also use "front end" and "back end", but we can also use "coté serveur" et "coté client" to translate it:

> Le Javascript est généralement utilisé en Front end, et le PHP en Back end

### Framework

As specified in [this post](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8492/7321), we commonly use "**framework**", it is hard to translate, except with "structure logicielle", but framework is definitely the most common one.

> Zend est un framework connu en PHP

### Server side

"Server side" is translated as "coté serveur":

> L'application est codée en PHP coté serveur

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice explanation. Can you point out any other major flaws in the CV I provided?

Comment: Indeed, there are many... Actually, could you re-write it without red notes ? I can't understand some sentences... Are you level B2 in french ? Your CV (before red notes) looks about B1 (maybe it's an exercise and it is not your CV ?). Once you've rewritten it, you could open a question for each part, saying what sound weird for you, and what you think translations could be.

Comment: I am B2.I don't think it is allowed to ask corrections for a CV in here though.

Comment: @samayo Indeed, you can't post your CV and ask us to correct it. That's why I detailed the way you must do it to be accepted here :)